# Weird White Border around background image

Tags: html, css

I'm currently setting up a website but can't seem to pinpoint what is causing this **strange White border** around the main Background image @ `kashmirwala (dot) com`

Does anyone know how I can get rid of it?

Comment: what have you used so far to pinpoint it and failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border is from the image (bitmap) itself, not from html/css.. As you can see opening the original image url http://static1.squarespace.com/static/569e1eecc647ad7c16303bec/569f73e905caa7c172811464/56b396e62eeb81c40dfd03bd/1454610153863/homepage+4.jpg

Comment: Thank you!  We have a solution! I can't believe I've just spent a few hours without realizing that.

Comment: No problem, sometimes we are so close to the problem that we just can't see it... If my answer solves the case please check it as the correct answer.

Comment: For sure, Fresh eyes or stepping back  for  a moment I keep forgetting that. I've marked, voted, & sent my love.